# Is there a way to increase xdebug profile call tree depth?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to use xdebug to determine what's causing a page to load slowly and the profiler snapshot doesn't show enough depth in the call tree tab (I'm using PhpStorm).

The call tree tab looks like this:

```
index.php
  ..
  ..
  my_file.php
    function1
    function2
    ...
```

It shows my_file.php  as taking up over 90% of the time, but it doesn't go deep enough in the call tree for me to see what functions are taking the time up. I can mostly figure this out from the execution statistic tab, which shows each individual function, but it would be great if the call tree tab would go deeper.

Is there a setting to allow this?

Here are my xdebug settings:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "callgrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "E:\wamp\www\xdebug_profiler"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 100
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

I've just received the canonical answer from Derick Rethans, the author of xdebug, and it looks like my answer was indeed correct! From correspondence on the xdebug-general mailing list:

> > Hi folks,
> >
> > Is there a limit to the depth of the call stack in the profiling
> >     feature of xdebug?
>
> No, there isn't.
>
> > Using PHP Storm as a front end, I can see my_file.php taking over 90%
> >     of the time, but the graph doesn't go deep enough in the call tree to
> >     see what functions are taking up the time.
>
> I know that kcachegrind doesn't show things if they take up less than
>   5% by default. Perhaps phpstorm does that too?
>
> > I'm able to see what functions are taking up the most time in the
> >     execution statistic tab, however it would be nice to see how the code
> >     is arriving at the rogue function call.
>
> Difficult to see for me, without profile file, and a pointer as what
>   you would expect...

### Original Answer

It's an interesting question and curious where the limitation might be imposed. The reason being PHP's built-in [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) prints the entire stack trace by default. The `$limit` argument was only added in 5.4...

Also *skimming* the xdebug source I didn't see any value or code which would limit the call stack collection. That said I've seen no configuration option to influence the number of function calls captured by the profiler either...

So the short answer is **no**.

Some thoughts and suggestions though

1. Use the execution statistic tab to find the rogue function. Call `die(print_debug_backtrace())` from that function. That should give you a stack trace through to said rogue function.
2. Again using the execution statistic tab to find the rogue function, use xdebug's [function trace feature](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) to take it from there (less desirable than a cachegrind UI I know, but in lieu of that...)
3. Clear the `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` before you load the page when gathering a profile. If there are multiple output files, make sure to inspect all of them in the cachegrind UI. Along these lines consider adding a random value `xdebug.profiler_output_name = "callgrind.out.%t-%s-%r"` just to rule out files overwriting one another (this has happened to me and can be *very* frustrating once you realize it's the problem).
4. Try another cachegrind visualizer. While I doubt this is the issue, who knows, as a last resort, I'd say it's worth a shot.
5. Lastly, for a canonical answer, you could post on the xdebug mailing list *ecartis@lists.xdebug.org*, or ask the author himself. They suggest asking on SO first, which you've done, so the list and author may be receptive to the inquiry. Details on the [xdebug support page](http://xdebug.org/support.php).

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth
```

To higher value (default is 3).

Other variables that might be set are listed here:
http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_depth

Comment: I have `var_display_max_depth = 100` in my configuration and it didn't change anything..

Comment: This setting pertains to **function traces**, not **profiling**, per the documentation you linked to... "Controls how many nested levels of array elements and object properties are when variables are displayed with either xdebug_var_dump(), xdebug.show_local_vars or through Function Traces."